# State of activity calling startActivity(Intent)

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

Can someone help me. What method of activity life cycle is called when the activity start new activity by method `startActivity(Intent)`? I thought, that it is `onPause()`, but it can not be. I have it override to close SQLite connection, but it not happen.

Thanks

Sorry, maybe I described my problem wrong. Activity A start another activity B. My question is what method of activity A is called after start activity B by method `startActivity(Intent)`.

Answer (score 3):

it runs into `onPause` then `onStop`. I tested it...

Comment: How about `onDestroy`?

Answer (score 0):

Check http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

The onCreate is called when an activity gets started.

Answer (score 0):

Because you start a new activity, that was not started before the method that gets called is `onCreate`. 
From the android developers site:

> onCreate is where you initialize your activity. Most
>   importantly, here you will usually call setContentView(int) with a
>   layout resource defining your UI, and using findViewById(int) to
>   retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with
>   programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could just override both methods to check whether one of them is called. Just put an log output to each. Once you find the right one and the connection isn't closed ... maybe your close call is wrong.

```
Log.d("DEBUG", "Here in method METHODNAME")
```